# Automatically Changing the Text Size to Accommodate Space

Tags: ios

I am building a tvOS application but I think the question applies to iOS in general. I am using a UILabel in my application. Sometimes the text is 4-5 lines and it fit perfectly on the screen. but sometimes the text is 10-12 lines which cuts of OR displays over other controls etc. How can I adjust that if the text is 10-12 lines then the app automatically adjust the size of the text to accommodate the space.

Hopefully, there is something built in to the iOS framework!!

Comment: Just commenting, since I haven't played with the TV sdk.. In IB, labels get "autoshrink" property were you can tell it to change font size to fit.

Comment: Do I have to specify the height for the UILabel? Currently, I do not have any height. noOfLines is zero and word wraps